# how the html tag is placed outside the query while or foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

I show my sql data in the horizontalTab.
The Groups and subgroups from the database on the left and far right.
But I do not know why html tags just show my query.
Please help how the html tag is placed outside the query while or foreach

```
       <div id="horizontalTab" >
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tab-1">sample</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div id="tab-1">
                  sample
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and my query

```
<div id="horizontalTab" class="col-md-12">
  <ul >
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
      $query = $db->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute();
      $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      foreach ($row as $rs) { ?>

        <li ><a href="#tab-1"><?php echo $rs['name'] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM `sub-category`
                    WHERE catid = '".$rs['id']."'";
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $subcat = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach ($subcat as $row2) { ?>
                <div id="tab-1">
                  <?php echo $row2['name'] ?></a>


            <?php } ?>

        </li>

      <?php } ?>
      </div>
  </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: I think you should join category and sub-category in the first query and then use the data in both foreach loops. your code will be much quicker and easier to maintain